# This tag does not pass [inspect]ion

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I feel like [inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspect) shouldn't exist on this site as it is too vague in meaning. Let's go through the criteria for burnination:

---

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied and is unambiguous?**
In my opinion, it's basically entirely ambiguous. It doesn't really add information besides that some kind of inspection is taking place which really could mean anything (see last criteria).

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
Not by default but the big majority is on topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
No, it doesn't. An inspection of any kind could mean a lot of things.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
Not at all. Many questions are about element inspector tools present in most browsers. These should be retagged to [web-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-inspector). Another large chunk is about the [python standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) with the same name. It should probably get its own tag as other standard modules already have (e.g. [python-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-os)). The last sizable group of questions is about [the docker command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) which should also get its own tag.

---

I think this tag should be burninated as it does not serve any purpose. No person could possibly be using this tag to find anything as the result is a pile of random questions from all sorts of different areas of knowledge. I therefore propose the following action plan:

1. Create [python-inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-inspect) and [docker-inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-inspect)
2. Retag all questions with [inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspect) and `[python*]` to [python-inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-inspect)
3. Retag all questions with [inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspect) and any web-related tag ([html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), `[google-chrome*]`, `[firefox*]`, `[internet-explorer*]`, `[microsoft-edge*]`, [android-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-webview), [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser), `[web*]`) to [web-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-inspector)
4. Retag all questions with [inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspect) and `[docker*]` to [docker-inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-inspect)
5. Review the remaining [149 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspect+-python+-python-3.x+-python-2.7+-python-requests+-python-imaging-library+-python-3.6+-python-import+-python-asyncio+-python-3.7+-python-3.5+-python-multiprocessing+-python-multithreading+-python-sphinx+-python-2.x+-python-3.4+-python-unittest+-python-decorators+-python-module+-python-2.6+-python-idle+-docker+-docker-compose+-dockerfile+-docker-swarm+-docker-machine+-docker-registry+-docker-volume+-docker-for-windows+-docker-container+-dockerhub+-docker-image+-docker-networking+-docker-desktop+-docker-build+-docker-toolbox+-docker-swarm-mode+-docker-for-mac+-dockerpy+-docker-network+-docker-stack+-web-services+-web+-webpack+-web-scraping+-websocket+-web-applications+-webview+-webforms+-webdriver+-web-crawler+-web-config+-webserver+-webrtc+-webkit+-websphere+-weblogic+-webgl+-webstorm+-webbrowser-control+-web-deployment+-html+-css+-javascript+-browser+-google-chrome+-google-chrome-extension+-google-chrome-devtools+-google-chrome-app+-google-chrome-headless+-google-chrome-os+-google-chrome-arc+-google-chrome-storage+-google-chrome-frame+-google-chrome-console+-google-chrome-flags+-google-chrome-webview+-google-chrome-theme+-firefox+-firefox-addon+-firefox-addon-sdk+-firefox-webextensions+-firefox-os+-firefox-developer-tools+-firefox4+-firefox3.6+-firefox-marionette+-firefox-3+-firefox-addon-restartless+-firefox-developer-edition+-firefox-profile+-firefox-quantum+-firefox-android+-firefox3.5+-firefox-5+-firefox-headless+-firefox-driver+-firefox-sidebar+-internet-explorer+-internet-explorer-8+-internet-explorer-11+-internet-explorer-9+-internet-explorer-7+-internet-explorer-6+-internet-explorer-10+-internet-explorer-5+-internet-explorer-driver+-internet-explorer-3+-microsoft-edge+-microsoft-edge-extension+-microsoft-edge-chromium+-android-webview)
6. Remove (and blacklist) [inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspect)

Last, but not least: Thank you, [yivi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi), for the great title!

Comment: I did an [tag:inspection] of this tag and I agree something needs to be done about it.

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new inspect overlords.

Comment: @user4581301 Best reference I've read all year :,D

Comment: 100% agreement from a random user (me).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html