# Stop keeping up our [appearance]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appearance) tag is very unclear

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Obviously no, what could "appearance" mean?

Tags used with [appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appearance):

- [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customization)
- [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode)/[eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)
- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- etc..

This is very very broad, it could refer to:

- appearance of an app
- appearance of a website
- The `appearance` property in CSS (we have the [webkit-appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webkit-appearance) tag for this)
- appearance/customization of a text editor/IDE
- etc..

Therefore it is not possible for someone to be an expert in [appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appearance)

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It tells that the question is related to appearance. But again, this is obviously a meaningless and useless information as the tag is ambiguous.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, as I already stated in the second point

**Is the topic described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes and no, It could relate to programming topics but the definition of the tag is not really on-topic for the site

**Is the tag harmful?**

This tag has not been used a lot of times (312 questions), but some users use this tag for off-topic questions like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452308/android-studio-settings-and-appearance) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014135/macos-x-mojave-light-and-dark-appearance-mode-toggles) so it is somewhat harmful(?).

There is no tag wiki information for the [appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appearance) tag, but it has been around for almost 13 years.  Most of the top answerers have answered just one question (two have answered 2 and one has answered 3); similarly, all the top askers have asked just one question.

Comment: I wonder should these be mostly just retagged to [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface)

Comment: [webkit-appearance] is one specific CSS engine's implementation of the `appearance` property. It wouldn't work for, say, Firefox's implementation. [css-appearance] should be created for those questions, if needed.

Comment: @CodyGray:  You felt it necessary to moderate away the title, *Let's discuss this tag's dis[appearance]* because "the pun needs to use the actual word/phrase from the tag, not a modified form of it."   Seriously?

Comment: I suggest using "Stop keeping up our \[appearance\]s" instead of "Stop keeping up our \[appearance\]" as *[keep up appearances](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_up_appearances#Verb)* is idiomatic.

Comment: Precedents for the title: [I'm feeling rather anti\[social\] today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410740/6045800), [This \[proto\]type was a failure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409121/6045800), [This tag does not pass \[inspect\]ion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402934/6045800)

Comment: "Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts" - I would say yes. In all those contexts, the semantic meaning is pretty similar. (As opposed to tags where there are say three completely different products that happen to have used the same Greeek god's name or something.)

Comment: I wonder what outfits the expert of [tag:appearance] wears himself. Seriously: it's a useless tag, any question about UI (or even a simple output) implicitly imply appearance. When it's a general design question, then there is [dedicated site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).  Otherwise more *precise* tags required, e.g. a control which is in question.

Comment: I agree with @Steve; I also dispute that the tag is "unclear". It's most certainly *broad*, but "appearance" very clearly means "the way someone/ thing looks" (whether that thing is a website, app, interface, etc.); that's not unclear in any meaningful way. There might still be reasons to burn this tag, but lack of clear meaning isn't one of them.

Comment: I'm prepared to assert that someone can be an expert in appearance but I'm not willing to lift one finger to save this tag all the same. Send rather to stackexchange ux.

Comment: This tag has the [appearance] of being bad.

Comment: I feel like this burninate-request is a classic example of what's wrong with the 4 questions. Someone decides "this tag is bad", and then just answers "yes it's bad" to all 4 questions. In this case, the meaning is clear and consistent, it does describe the contents of those questions, it probably does add some meaningful information (although maybe not much), and most instances would be on topic (unless they're subjective questions about what would look best). It's not a great tag, but it does pass most of those tests.

Comment: For iOS, it probably could be replaced with `[UIAppearance]`